# WPF: Can a ListViewItem call method with its index as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, caliburn

I have a `ListBox` declared in xaml, where its `ItemsSource` is binding to an `ObservableCollection`. Working in `MVVM`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Arguments}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CArgumentClass}">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArgName}" ToolTip="{Binding Documentation}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueToShow, TargetNullValue=Missing}"/>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

I can attach a command to the list box events. I'm working with `Caliburn` framework, but there are many other ways to do that. I can also send parameter to the method, in this example I send the data context:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Arguments}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CArgumentClass}">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"
                        cal:Message.Attach="DeleteArgument($dataContext)]"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArgName}" ToolTip="{Binding Documentation}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueToShow, TargetNullValue=Missing}"/>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

My question is, can I send the item index to the method? How?

Note this code is made up for the question, my purpose is to delete items from list from the view, by the user, in a simple way. The items in list are not focusable.

Comment: you may perhaps send the item and get the index from the original collection in the command handler. it may get little complex in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking  [pushpraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612760/pushpraj) comment as the answer: Let the command handler search the index.

Comment: indeed that is one of the easiest solution to this issue.